# publish git repository on webspace

Tags: git, repository, hosting, publish

I'm new to the concept of version control and just started using git a few days ago. I think it's a very cool way to manage projects and I'm planning to create my own website using git.

I basically know how to use it. I have a repository on bitbucket. But I don't understand how to publish a project from a repository. So I want to have all my code in it and when I'm finished I want to get all the files in my webspace, without uploading it manually. Is there any way to do this?

Git seems to be really useful and I also like bitbucket, but I absolutely don't understand how to publish the files on my webspace after working in the repository. Sorry if the answer is obvious, I googled a lot and didn't find a good answer.

By the way: I haven't chosen a web hosting service yet, so please tell me if something like SSH is required for what I want to do. I don't have root access.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.therealtimeweb.com/index.cfm/2012/5/16/move-git-repo-to-bitbucket

Comment: I am really lost as to what you are asking. What do you mean "publish to your webspace"?

Comment: I have all project files (php, javascript, html) in my git repository on bitbucket. When I'm finished with the project I want to uplaod the files on my webspace to "publish" the project on my homepage. I could download the latest files from bitbucket and uplaod it manually, but is there any way to pull the files from the repository to my webspace? Because if I want to make changed or add features later, I'd have to do the same thing again.. downlaod the latest files and uplaod them to my ftp again. I just want to automatically copy all the latest file from the repository to my webspace via git

Answer (score 0):

There's a decent guide to doing this here: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto although you will need SSH access to your web host.